# How to know from where ViewComponent is being called in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

Let's say, I have MenuViewComponent

```
public class MenuViewComponent : ViewComponent
{

    public MenuViewComponent()
    {
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        return  View();
    }
}
```

And it's being Invoked from multiple razor views

for example in

```
1.TopMenu.cshtml -> @await Component.InvokeAsync("Menu")
2.SideMenu.cshtml -> @await Component.InvokeAsync("Menu")
```

Now, the problem is I can't modify the component code to add any extra info.
Is there any way to know whether the component is called from TopMenu.cshtml or SideMenu.cshtml
by changing the code inside

```
~/View/shared/Components/Menu/Default.cshtml
```

Comment: You could not get the calling view in Default view.There is no call hierarchy.A recommend way is to pass the viewname as parameter when call the viewcomponent.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.2#walkthrough-creating-a-simple-view-component

Answer (score 3):

Your class is inheriting from ViewComponent class. ViewComponent class has many methods in inside.

**You can get the view path from ViewContext.**

```
ViewContext.View.Path
```

This property returns a value like this

```
"/Views/Home/Index.cshtml"
```

**ViewComponent.cs includes**

```
public abstract class ViewComponent
    {
        protected ViewComponent();

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal for the current user.
        public ClaimsPrincipal UserClaimsPrincipal { get; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary.
        public ViewDataDictionary ViewData { get; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponent.ViewContext.
        public ViewContext ViewContext { get; }
        [ViewComponentContext]
        public ViewComponentContext ViewComponentContext { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IUrlHelper.
        public IUrlHelper Url { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary.
        public ModelStateDictionary ModelState { get; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the view bag.
        [Dynamic]
        public dynamic ViewBag { get; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponent.RouteData for the current request.
        public RouteData RouteData { get; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ICompositeViewEngine.
        public ICompositeViewEngine ViewEngine { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal for the current user.
        public IPrincipal User { get; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest.
        public HttpRequest Request { get; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext.
        public HttpContext HttpContext { get; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ITempDataDictionary.
        public ITempDataDictionary TempData { get; }

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Returns a result which will render HTML encoded text.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   content:
        //     The content, will be HTML encoded before output.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     A Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponents.ContentViewComponentResult.
        public ContentViewComponentResult Content(string content);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Returns a result which will render the partial view with name viewName.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   viewName:
        //     The name of the partial view to render.
        //
        //   model:
        //     The model object for the view.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     A Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponents.ViewViewComponentResult.
        public ViewViewComponentResult View<TModel>(string viewName, TModel model);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Returns a result which will render the partial view with name "Default".
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   model:
        //     The model object for the view.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     A Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponents.ViewViewComponentResult.
        public ViewViewComponentResult View<TModel>(TModel model);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Returns a result which will render the partial view with name viewName.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   viewName:
        //     The name of the partial view to render.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     A Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponents.ViewViewComponentResult.
        public ViewViewComponentResult View(string viewName);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Returns a result which will render the partial view with name "Default".
        //
        // Returns:
        //     A Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponents.ViewViewComponentResult.
        public ViewViewComponentResult View();
    }
```

**But I prefer you to send a parameter to your viewcomponent. Like an enum. (Menu.TopMenu and Menu.SideMenu)**

Comment: I'll mention that `RouteData` contains helpful information about `Controller`/`Action` or `Area` of the request. `RouteData.Values["controller"]`

Comment: @Sinan ViewContext.View.Path didn't help  however RouteData did

Comment: I think you should send a parameter to your viewcomponent. It's more useful. Like @await Component.InvokeAsync("Menu", MenuType.SideMenu) Isn't it enough for you?